# Keep javascript running on different pages

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I have a javascript that does some work then goes to another page.
I have it in a couple versions:

One is a bookmarklet, the other is a script for tampermonkey and js code.
Once it's there though I can't find a way to continue having it run.

I know javascript runs on the page but is there a way to have it server sided or something so that when the page is changed to another the script can continue once the page is loaded?

**What I want**:

- I press button,
- stuff happens,
- I'm redirected to another page,
- stuff happens again,
- redirected,
- stuff happens...
- etc.

But I want it to not need any user input rather then the initial starting.

I have the code to the point where it does stuff then redirects but I don't know how to have it continue on the different page.

Comment: Are you not able to save its state i.e. a cookie,localStorage or sessionStorage when you leave a page. Then when you load the second page, read the state of the cookie and continue based on the value of the state.

Comment: This is possible but details matter.  Be specific about what you are doing and exactly how the URLs differ.  Or are the page(s) AJAX driven?

Comment: @BrockAdams I'm trying to make a script to like multiple page after page of forum post. so forum/thread/page-1 then /page-2 and so one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a method of some stuff happening and place this method on common js file that is linked on every page and call that method on every page $(document).ready(fucntion(){}) event.

```
function anyMethodName(){
    //Do your required stuff here.
}
```

and call it on $(document).ready(fucntion(){}) like:

```
$(document).ready(fucntion(){ anyMethodName(); })
```

Comment: the thing is its not my page. It's little script for a forum.

Comment: never mind I got it to work. I just put $(document).ready(fucntion(){ anyMethodName(); }); after the function in my tamper monkey code and now it auto runs in the page i want it to. thank you